# qt moveToThread slot function not called

Tags: multithreading, qt

controller.h:

```
#ifndef CONTROLLER_H
#define CONTROLLER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QThread>

class Controller : public QObject
{

    Q_OBJECT
    QThread workerThread;
public:
    Controller(QObject *parent = 0);

    ~Controller();

public slots:
    void handleResults(const QString &str);
signals:
    void operate(const QString &str);
};

#endif // CONTROLLER_H
```

controller.cpp:

```
#include "controller.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include "worker.h"

Controller::Controller(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent), workerThread()
{
    Worker *worker = new Worker;
    connect(&workerThread, &QThread::finished, worker, &QObject::deleteLater);
    connect(this, &Controller::operate, worker, &Worker::doWork, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    connect(worker, &Worker::resultReady, this, &Controller::handleResults, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    worker->moveToThread(&workerThread);
    workerThread.start();
}

Controller::~Controller()
{
    workerThread.quit();
    workerThread.wait();
}

void Controller::handleResults(const QString &str)
{
    qDebug()<<"handleResult:"<<str;
}
```

worker.h:

```
#ifndef WORKER_H
#define WORKER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QThread>
#include <QDebug>

class Worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
public slots:
      void doWork(const QString &parameter);
signals:
      void resultReady(const QString &result);
};

#endif // WORKER_H
```

worker.cpp:

```
#include "worker.h"
#include <QDebug>

void Worker::doWork(const QString &parameter) {
    /* ... here is the expensive or blocking operation ... */

   qDebug()<<"doWork:"<<parameter;
   emit resultReady(parameter);
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "worker.h"
#include <QTimer>
#include <QEvent>
#include "controller.h"


int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

    Controller con;
    while(1)
    {
        QString str = "hello";
        emit con.operate(str);
        QThread::sleep(1);
    }
    return app.exec();
}
```

I would like to call the doWork slot function via the operate signal, the resultReady signal will be issued before the doWork function is executed, but the slot function handleResults is not executed.

function doWork can be called, but why slot handleResults not called?

Comment: Your event loop never starts meaning queued signals will never be delivered.

Comment: `while(1)` is not allowing your event loop to start. Use a `QTimer` instead of a `while` loop.

Comment: but why slot doWork can be called

Comment: Because it lives in a different thread, and that thread has a running event loop. See [`QThread::exec`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#exec)

Comment: Thank you for your reply